# Qual a origem da expressão "perguntas de algibeira"

Tags: significado, expressões, origem-histórica, origem

Durante uma conversa com um professor, surgiu a expressão **"perguntas de algibeira"**.

Embora se perceba o contexto para a utilização da expressão, nenhum de nós sabia a origem da expressão e o seu significado concreto.

Acabei por consultar o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/pergunta), que tem:

> A que parece fácil mas que é feita inesperadamente, visando sobretudo
> confundir ou embaraçar o interpelado.

No entanto, fica a dúvida sobre a origem da expressão.

Comment: Acredito que essa expressão seja regional. Se não se sentir desconfortável para responder, em que região/estado você mora?

Comment: A expressão é utilizada bastante em Portugal. Eu estou na região de Leiria e o meu professor na região de Lisboa (100km de distância).